# How to configure SonarQube (with jacoco) on multi module android project (kotlin + java)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco

I have seen different approaches with different specification: only java, only single module, with jacoco exec file or xml report for sonarqube, sonarqube.gradle included in all modules or only in root.... and tried a lot. At the end I struggled always and some of my requirements don't work.

Does anyone have an approach that fit all my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a test project which fill all my needs in my [github repo](https://github.com/logerom/android-java-kotlin-jacoco)

The key facts are that you have to put you sonar task in your root gradle file and the jacoco one at any module in your project.

The important **sonar properties** are:
`sonar.host.url`and  `sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`

For the **jacoco** task you have to define your java-Classes `"../app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes/de/logerbyte/jacocotest/javaClasses"`, your kotlin-Classes `"../app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug/de/logerbyte/jacocotest"` and your normal src `"../app/src/main/java"` for every module.

With these information you have to set the properties `classDirectories`, `executionData` and `sourceDirectoriers`in your own created jacoco task.

At the end you run the gradle tasks for `build`, `testDebugUnitTest`, `jacocoTestReport` and `sonarqube`.

Comment: thanks for this! in case others wondering for the aggregated reports (a single reports for all of my multi module), explained in a brief here: https://medium.com/swlh/sonarqube-for-multi-module-android-app-20e42147d4ff#:~:text=all%20test%20execution%20data